# Is there a way to query sandbox configuration info? (e.g. Location, sandbox name, etc)

Tags: api, metadata-api, sandbox, tooling-api, configuration

I would like to be able to query the Sandbox configuration data.  For example, if you go to the "Sandboxes" link in the setup of your production org, I want to be able to query that info (Name, Type, Location, Current Org Id, etc) via soql or via an API call.

Does anyone know if there's a way this can be done?  Tooling API, metadata API, native soql, etc?

Comment: I haven't looked at it in depth yet, but there are new sandbox management enhancements coming in Winter '16. See [Sandbox Enhancements](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandbox.htm). There is also the [SandboxInfo object in the v35.0 Tooling API](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_api_tooling.htm). Again, I don't have a production org on Winter 16 to test it with yet.

Comment: Ah that looks promising.  I will take a look once I have a Winter 16 org to play with.  Thanks

Comment: As lame as it sounds, I created a web scraper in Kimono that grabs all the data from that page. Then I just all that api to get that data, and personally load it into a custom object that I can then query from wherever I need to. It works, but doesn't use any Salesforce API's to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not directly what you are looking for, but I stumbled across the [Sandbox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm#sandbox) EventLogFile.

Description from the docs:

> Sandbox events contain details about sandbox copies.

Of particular interest were some of the fields that it captures:

- CURRENT_SANDBOX_ORG_ID - The 15-character ID of the current sandbox organization.
- PENDING_SANDBOX_ORG_ID - The 15-character ID of the target sandbox org.
- SANDBOX_ID - The 15-character ID of the sandbox organization.
- STATUS - The status of the sandbox copy.

The catch here is that Event Logs are a paid feature. Still, it may be useful if you can get it. When available, you can access it with both the REST and SOAP apis.

Answer (score 0):

We can query using Tooling API on `SandboxInfo`.

```
SELECT Id, LicenseType , SandboxName FROM SandboxInfo
```

But you can run this query in Production org only.

If you are in current sandbox and want some detail then make a SOQL on organization:

```
SELECT createddate, IsSandbox, InstanceName, OrganizationType FROM Organization
```