# Way to get the sandbox host from ToolingAPI

Tags: sandbox, tooling-api

Looking at the new-ish [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) and [SandboxProcess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxprocess.htm#topic-title) objects I don't see anyway to get the pod name (ie, NA7, CS16, etc).  Is there a way to get this information from the ToolingAPI, or do I have to do something like login to each of the sandboxes from the list to get the serverUrl?

I saw this [older post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94748/is-there-a-way-to-query-sandbox-configuration-info-e-g-location-sandbox-name) which mentions these objects but doesn't quite have the same information that I'm looking for.

Comment: It would be a bit of a Heath Robinson Solution, but you could using the `PENDING_SANDBOX_ORG_ID` from the [event log file](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/94884/102) to extrapolate the pod using [Converting the Salesforce Pod Id to ServerUrl/Name](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/7664/102). People are often negative towards this as a possible solution, but I think it could be made to work here.

Comment: The negativity usually comes from the extrapolation breaking when an org is migrated. I don't think that will be a problem for sandbox refreshes.

Comment: I think the biggest problem with that is having to have the additional entitlement required for the event log to get this information.  Additionally, if there are sandboxes that were created longer that the 30 retention cap of the event log then you will not have the data available.

Comment: Yeah, less than ideal. Another Crazy Untested Idea™: Use a [SandboxPostCopy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm) event to send the SandboxContext details back to the parent org. I'm not sure if you can make a callout in a post copy context (Remote site settings?), or the best way to authenticate with the production org. It probably also falls into the too many potential problems and too much effort category.